# How to attach to child process in LLDB

Tags: macos, process, lldb

My process starts child processes and I want to debug these as well, using LLDB on OS X. I can't find any option in the debugger to auto-attach. How to do it?

Comment: Related: [lldb equivalent of gdb's "follow-fork-mode" or "detach-on-fork"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204395/lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-follow-fork-mode-or-detach-on-fork)

Answer (score 20):

Google is really silent on this issue, but I found a workaround.

Run your main process and stop it before it spins off any children. Then put a breakpoint on the function `fork`:

```
b fork
```

and let the program continue. When it is about to launch a child process, the breakpoint will be hit. At this moment, run another instance of LLDB and let it wait and autoattach to your process:

```
attach -w -n yourapp
```

Now let the parent program continue.

Comment: How should I create another instance of `lldb`?

Comment: open another terminal window and run lldb in the command line

Comment: The `attach -w -n` syntax is for gdb. In lldb it's `process attach -n myapp -w`, which can be abbreviated to `pro at -n myapp -w`. http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: I had difficulty getting lldb to attach because my child process was crashing immediately (`attach failed: process did not stop (no such process or permission problem?`). Adding a `sleep` call to slow things down gave lldb time to attach.

Comment: I've found a good solution. read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161144/command-line-application-how-to-attach-a-child-process-to-xcode-debugger)

Comment: @inherithandle You can open two terminal tabs, one is for parent process and the other is for child process. Execute commands `lldb a.out; lldb> b fork; lldb> run` to start parent process. when the parent process stop at breakpoint(before it spins off children) , you can use command `lldb; pro at -n a.out -w` in the second terminal tab. The second lldb will catch the children process forked from parent process.

Comment: When I try this, I get "error: attach failed: lost connection."

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17972 seems to be a relevant LLDB issue.