# How Xcode can follow child process on debug mode?

Tags: xcode, sockets, fork, lldb

I'm trying to implement multiple process server in C. I'd like to check child process step by step. But on default debug mode, I have no choice to follow parent process, calling `fork` function. And google does not help me lead to what I want.
How Xcode can follow child process on debug mode?
Any help or web page would be awesome.

Comment: `lldb` (supplied with Xcode 4.6.2) seems broken when setting a breakpoint in a function called by the child process (I get `EXC_BREAKPOINT SIGTRAP`, which is fine when the breakpoint hits in the parent process).  I think you'll need a separate `lldb` instance to debug the child.

Comment: How should I create a separate `lldb` instance? Is there any useful web page?

Comment: I've tried the technique explained in the following answer, to no avail.  I simply cannot stop `lldb` crashing when the child process hits the breakpoint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746315/how-to-attach-to-child-process-in-lldb

Comment: I've found a good solution. read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161144/command-line-application-how-to-attach-a-child-process-to-xcode-debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode uses LLDB, and that currently doesn't support this. The issue to add the support is https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17972