# Command line application: How to attach a child process to xcode debugger?

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, child-process

I'm currently making a command line app in C in which many child process is created. So I need to debug this children code. I have created a child process on Xcode as follow. (see the break point and running cursor.)

[image]

After executing some statements, I get xcode to attach GBN(885) to the xcode debugger as shown in below figure.

[image] [image]

It doesn't work. How can I attach the child process to xcode debugger? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google and Apple developer page are really silent on this issue and finally I've found a good workaround. This error message appears when we get Xcode debugger to attach to the process that is a child process of process being debugged or that is a process already being debugged by Xcode debugger, gdb, or lldb.

[image: error message]

In order to avoid this irritating message, First put `kill(0, SIGSTOP)` statement where you want to stop the child process. In the following figure, I have put the `kill` statement right after the child is created.

[image]

Second, use `gcc` to compile your source codes with -g option.

```
$ ls
GBN.1  gbn.c  gbn.h  type.h util.c util.h
$ gcc *.c -g
$ ./a.out

[1]+  Stopped                 ./a.out
$ ps -ef | grep a.out
  501   628   600   0  9:33AM ttys000    0:00.00 ./a.out
  501   629   628   0  9:33AM ttys000    0:00.00 ./a.out
```

Now, all we have to do is to tell Xcode debugger to attach to the process by pid. Click the `Debug` menu and then find the `Attach to process` option to click `By Process Identifier (PID) or name` option. Then type the pid for child process (or parent process) and click attach button.

[image]

Enjoy Debugging!

[image]

Comment: Wonderful.  I never would have figured this out myself.

Comment: Calling this a "good" workaround is reallllly stretching the definition of "good". We've got a rather large service written in Swift, with external dependencies, not some two-C-files demo program that just `fork()`s. Putting a SIGSTOP into the debuggee is not a complete non-starter but is a real pain when we're trying to debug shipping code. Also, this won't help debug crashes due to race conditions where the child does something before the parent is ready; by the time the child resumes the race will be long since over.