# lldb equivalent of gdb's "follow-fork-mode" or "detach-on-fork"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, lldb

Does lldb have an equivalent to either of these gdb directives?
I'm trying to make it follow a child process instead of the parent without having to do this manual process:

1. break on fork
2. pgrep for the child process
3. spin up another lldb process and attach to the child
4. continue the parent

Some googling did not provide any insight.

Context: I'm using NSTask & injecting a dylib using dyld, and want to set breakpoints in my library without lots of pain. I'm pretty sure NSTask uses fork() internally.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746315/how-to-attach-to-child-process-in-lldb

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the aforementioned question. There's a difference between attaching to a child process and following both child+parent process. Not to mention, there's a difference between doing it automatically & manually - the answer for the given question does it manually, which I already list as my current workflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`follow-fork-mode` was [merged into LLDB's main branch](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/4a2a947317bf702178bf1af34dffd0d280d49970) and is available starting in version 14.0.0.

```
settings set target.process.follow-fork-mode child
```

If your version of LLDB is based on LLVM 14.0.0+ it should be available. Alternately you can build it from source or use `brew install llvm` (for macOS you would also have to [codesign lldb](https://lldb.llvm.org/resources/build.html#code-signing-on-macos)).

It is also available in Apple's CLI tools now since it updated to 14.0.0 ([with Xcode 14 by the look of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions)).

Comment: I tried this solution on macOS with Xcode 15.2 and directly on the command line and neither work for me. When the breakpoint is hit the child process crashes with EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP).

Comment: @hgs3 Maybe try creating a bug report.

Answer (score 4):

lldb does not currently support "follow-fork-mode".  You can often achieve the same effect using lldb's "attach --wait-for" or in Xcode by choosing the "wait for  to be launched manually" option in the Run scheme for the target you are debugging.  These will grab the first NEW occurrence of a process with the given name.

Comment: has `follow-fork-mode` not been implemented yet? :)