# Debug a C Child Process Using VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, fork, parent-child

I am using VScode with the following version details:

Version: 1.73.0 (user setup)
Commit: 8fa188b2b301d36553cbc9ce1b0a146ccb93351f
Date: 2022-11-01T15:34:06.111Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000
Sandboxed: No

I am unable to debug a child process when I use fork().

I tried looking for a way to do so, and heard about this extension for Visual Studio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool2022&ssr=false#overview

I tried checking in the extensions section of VSCode but didn't find it. So, I decided to manually install is by downloading the vsix file. When I tried installing it by using the "Install from VSIX" option in the extension manager, I get this error:

extension/package.json not found inside zip.

I did some more Googling and saw something about Visual Studio being different from Visual Studio Code, and that might be the cause of the error in installation.

So, is there any way/alternative around this? How do I debug a child process in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something outside of the main guides from VS Code, although they vaguely mentioned about supporting [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_multithreaded-debugging).

You can refer to the GDB's [fork](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) debug page for more info, here is what you can add into your [.vscode/launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference):

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {

            // ...

            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    // https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html
                    "description": "Fork follows Child process",
                    "text": "set follow-fork-mode child",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    // https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html
                    "description": "Fork will keep the other process attached to debugger",
                    "text": "set detach-on-fork off",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you're using LLDB or [codeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb), here is the [LLDB command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699331/19336104) that mirrors the above except the detach feature:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {

            // ...

            "initCommands": [
                "settings set target.process.follow-fork-mode child"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit**

I haven't used MSVC personally, but if you're using MSVC debugger, you can try to use `.childdbg 1`  as a startup command, here is the [reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-childdbg--debug-child-processes-) from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just used GDB and followed the instructions from the GDB link you provided.

Comment: @OlamideOlanrewaju If you could, try to follow the community's [good practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1160337) when a question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), it will be more helpful to indicate that your question already have a solution.

Comment: Oh. My bad. Didn't occur to me. I have done that now. Thanks.